# No. of groups I am member of is coming different using Azure AD graph and Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, authorization, azure-ad-graph-api

I have recently switched from Azure AD graph to Microsoft graph in my application. We are using it to get the list of groups the logged in user is a member of.
When using Azure AD graph URI: https://graph.windows.net/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/users/id@microsoft.com/memberOf?api-version=2013-04-05&$top=300 we are getting more than 200 groups for one user.
For the same user when using Microsoft Graph URI:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/id@microsoft.com/memberOf we are getting only 99 groups.

What could be the reason for this mismatch in numbers for this one user? For most users it is coming same in both.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Microsoft Graph, there is a limit size for each query. The limit for groups is 100. And the result has been paged.

Please see this document: [Paging Microsoft Graph data in your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging).

> Some queries against Microsoft Graph return multiple pages of data
> either due to server-side paging or due to the use of the `$top` query
> parameter to specifically limit the page size in a request. When a
> result set spans multiple pages, Microsoft Graph returns an
> `@odata.nextLink` property in the response that contains a URL to the
> next page of results.

We can use `@odata.nextLink` to get the next page of data until we reach to the final page.